# Corrigir sobreposição de elementos HTML?

Tags: html, css, e-commerce

Gostaria de adicionar conteudo num bloco da plataforma (como mostra captura- texto vermelho).

Ao adicionar um elemento por defeito ele fica no fin do bloco ( à baixo da imagen visa).

eu gostaria que a minha div ficasse entre o preço **34,78$TTC -5% ..** e a **quantité**.

**Fiz de seguinte modo :**

```
<div style="color: red; border: 1px solid #DFDFDF; position: relative; bottom: 405px; padding: 5px; word-break: break-word; margin : 3px 0 3px 0;" class="col-md-12" >
    Aqui esta o meu texto vermelho. Aqui esta o meu texto vermelho. Aqui esta o meu texto vermelho.
</div>
```

**Consequencias :**

- sobre posição de divs.

Como faço pra evitar isso editando simplesmente a minha div sem tocar no codigo do bloco da plataforma?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pode colocar o html e css dos outros elementos ?

Comment: `.col-md-12` deve ficar dentro de `<div class="row"></div>`, se usar da maneira que usa vai quebrar mesmo.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento a minha pergunta nao tem nada a ver com a tal suposta duplicata !

Comment: Então de detalhes por favor, pois ali na resposta que linkei explica sobre o `<div class="row"></div>` e o teu código não mostra o uso do `<div class="row"></div>`.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento mesmo usando "row" nao muda nada !! No principio o texto estava por baixo da imagen "visa" ! Você tem uma ideia de como colocar a minha div entre 34,78$TTC -5% .. e a quantité. ?

Comment: Não é só ir lá e jogar o row aleatoriamente, deve ter algum problema no CSS ou algo a mais, não tem como apontar aonde é. A resposta que eu apontei explicar como usar o GRID esse é o basico, mas isto não quer dizer que vc não tenha outras partes do HTML ou CSS com problemas.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu publiquei o meu CSS e HTML!

Comment: Aquilo é só um trecho, aquilo ali não é nada, existe muito mais CSS na tua pagina e muito mais HTML, pode ser qualquer parte que desencadeia  o problema.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento  aqui esta o link do codigo : https://jsfiddle.net/p6x5q04w/. Na verdade eu so quero adicionar elemento nesse bloco !

Comment: André, o código tá todo "comprimido", deu até dor nos olhos, vc quer me fazer sofrer? :(

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento extrai direitamente do site ... https://www.alibabike.com/lunettes/21632-verres-de-lunettes-tifosi-veloce-readers-clear-reader-lens-20.html. Como você pode ver, trata-se do bloco do lado direito ! Gostaira de adicionar um elemento entre o preço e quantidade.

Comment: Entendi, vc pegou um código pronto, olha logo no começo (no `body`) tem um col sem row `<body id="product" class="product product-21632 product-verres-de-lunettes-tifosi-veloce-readers-clear-reader-lens-20 category-8151 category-lunettes hide-left-column hide-right-column lang_fr">
        <div class="box-info-product col-md-3">`, esse é um que deve ser corrigido. Deve ter um monte de probleminha, ainda mais não sendo teu HTML, talvez vc nem entenda o que foi feito :/

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento você viu o bloco do qual estou falando ? como você faria por exemplo pra adicionar uma diva là ( sem modificar o codigo do bloco )? (como mostra a imagen na publicacao)

Comment: O HTML tá todo comprimido e não tem esse HTML da sua pergunta lá dentro, e como eu disse deve ter mais problemas, ainda mais que vc esta pegando um código seu e que vc não entende bem. :/

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento acredito que nao estou a fazer perceber a minha questao...!

Comment: Mas teu código tá todo comprimido eu não tenho como analisar isso.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento na verdade nao tem codigo nenhum a ser analisado, e eu nem estou pedindo isso !! Vê a imagem que eu postei na publicacao ? Imagine que você tem duas divs, e no interior dessa div você tem três divs colocados na vertical. Como você faria por exemplo para trocar as posicoes das divs usando apenas CSS  ou JS se possivel(sem alterar a estrutura do HTML ) e sem que haja subreposicao das divs ?

Comment: A sobreposição é pela falta do row, se mesmo com row deu problema é porque outra parte daquele HTML que vc me enviou está causando um problema em cascata e só analisando ele como eu já disse. E do jeito que vc mandou o HTML todo comprimido eu não tenho como analisar.